# change string type list to type integer

Tags: c#

The list is below: I simply want to convert it to an integer list

```
   List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
```

How do I convert all of it's contents to int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var intList = list2.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`List.ConvertAll<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
List<int> ints = list2.ConvertAll<int>(int.Parse);
```

If you don't have a list you could use a `Select` with `int.Parse`:

```
List<int> ints = strings.Select(s=> int.Parse(s)).ToList();
```